# What is the difference between ByteBuffer and CharBuffer in Java NIO?

Tags: java, char, nio, bytebuffer

What is difference between ByteBuffer and CharBuffer in case java.nio package. Is it the same difference as byte and char has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see it like that. A ByteBuffer is a buffer for (8-bit) `byte` values while a CharBuffer holds (16-bit) `chars`.

Answer (score 5):

Mostly, yes - but `ByteBuffer`s also have operations for viewing a `ByteBuffer` as other kinds of buffer (e.g. `asDoubleBuffer`), and for putting other primitive types into the buffer, (e.g. `putLong`).

`CharBuffer` also implements `Appendable` and `CharSequence`, making it easier to work with for text operations.